# React Native - FlatList data from rest shows only half

Tags: javascript, list, react-native, custom-component

I make a request to a api rest, and it returns an array of 20 items and when I pass it as a parameter to a component with a flatlist, it only shows 10 items...

Can anyone explain why this happens?

> home.js

```
componentDidMount() {

    HomeApi.get().then( response => {
      console.warn(response.profiles.length); //return 20
        this.setState({
            profiles: response.profiles,
            loading: false
        });
    });

  }

  <CustomComponent profiles={this.state.profiles} loading={this.state.loading} />
```

> CustomComponent.js

```
export default class CustomComponent extends Component {


    render() {
        if (this.props.profiles){
            console.warn(this.props.profiles.length);  //Show 20
        }
        return (
            <View>
                { this.props.loading ? (
                    <View>
                      <ActivityIndicator />
                    </View>
                ) : (
                <FlatList
                    data={ this.props.profiles}
                    horizontal={true}
                    renderItem={({item}) => 
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => {
                                console.warn('press')
                            }}>
                            <UserBox user={item}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    }
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                />)}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

> UserBox.js

```
export default class UserBox extends Component {
  render() {

    const {name, bio, featured_image} = this.props.user

    return (
      <View style={styles.user}>
        <Image source={{ uri: featured_image }} style={styles.avatar}/>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.name}>{name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.bio}>{bio}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Before I had it with Listview and I changed it because I thought it was something I was deprecated, but it gave the same result...

```
Array from rest api => {
    "profiles": [
        {
            "id": 52,
            "name": "Dr. Jasen Prosacco",
            "profile_id": 1,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Dejon Kiehn",
            "location": "Lake Ellie",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Commodi nihil blanditiis est enim qui.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?23591",
            "email": "hershel24@example.org",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 53,
            "name": "Loyce Stehr",
            "profile_id": 2,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Antoinette Murray",
            "location": "Grantville",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Corrupti ad qui aut earum soluta.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?44684",
            "email": "jenkins.willie@example.com",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 54,
            "name": "Pearl Daugherty DVM",
            "profile_id": 3,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Camden Vandervort",
            "location": "Port Susan",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Unde autem odit sit non id ut aut.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?86224",
            "email": "bryana33@example.net",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 55,
            "name": "Demetris Wolff",
            "profile_id": 4,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Micaela Wyman",
            "location": "East Taylor",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Saepe sit repellendus aut eveniet sed.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?15353",
            "email": "sskiles@example.org",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 56,
            "name": "Felton Boyer",
            "profile_id": 5,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Winnifred Batz",
            "location": "Deangeloside",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Sit eum et magni corporis ut unde reiciendis.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?38995",
            "email": "igrimes@example.net",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 57,
            "name": "Prof. Elizabeth Ward II",
            "profile_id": 6,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Prof. Kieran Cummings II",
            "location": "New Briahaven",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Odio vero officia quia nemo.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?67307",
            "email": "ruecker.stephon@example.com",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 58,
            "name": "Mr. Casey McDermott PhD",
            "profile_id": 7,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Ramiro Ruecker",
            "location": "Devanview",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Praesentium ex praesentium tempora.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?37079",
            "email": "graham.joanne@example.com",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 59,
            "name": "Erich Murray",
            "profile_id": 8,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Bailey Hudson",
            "location": "Rauburgh",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Exercitationem laboriosam ut ut iusto dolorum.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?88371",
            "email": "aufderhar.leland@example.net",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 60,
            "name": "Mossie Schoen DVM",
            "profile_id": 9,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Nelda Kovacek",
            "location": "Cedrickfort",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Consectetur illo et neque beatae.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?47300",
            "email": "gcormier@example.com",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 61,
            "name": "Mercedes Sipes",
            "profile_id": 10,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Sidney Hayes",
            "location": "South Joanymouth",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Dolorum alias molestias magnam commodi nihil ea temporibus.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?80896",
            "email": "vsporer@example.com",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 62,
            "name": "Mr. Otho Schmidt",
            "profile_id": 11,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Mrs. Damaris VonRueden DVM",
            "location": "Nealstad",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Aut sequi soluta aut libero quia aperiam iste.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?83661",
            "email": "carroll.kaycee@example.com",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 63,
            "name": "Weldon Emard",
            "profile_id": 12,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Andy Nicolas",
            "location": "Turcotteburgh",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Aut illo aperiam est facere quod dolores libero.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?41762",
            "email": "akilback@example.org",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 64,
            "name": "Dr. Adolfo Gleason I",
            "profile_id": 13,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Alexane Quitzon Sr.",
            "location": "Port Warrenmouth",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Magnam temporibus maiores ullam aut.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?68933",
            "email": "madonna.reynolds@example.com",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 65,
            "name": "Lennie Carroll",
            "profile_id": 14,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Miss Idell Ondricka DVM",
            "location": "North Imaberg",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Omnis dolores dolor excepturi reprehenderit quos.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?36188",
            "email": "felipe.kohler@example.org",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 66,
            "name": "Miss Shana Satterfield V",
            "profile_id": 15,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Anais Witting",
            "location": "Powlowskiview",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Quia error quam cum qui.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?50264",
            "email": "pollich.rogelio@example.com",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 67,
            "name": "Ubaldo Gusikowski",
            "profile_id": 16,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Dr. Gunner Considine",
            "location": "Davisport",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Amet asperiores nam aliquid quis dolorem.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?48372",
            "email": "paltenwerth@example.org",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 68,
            "name": "Shanel Johnson",
            "profile_id": 17,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Trace Heathcote",
            "location": "Smithburgh",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Ipsam debitis aliquam earum sunt totam dolorem ad.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?57650",
            "email": "hills.pablo@example.net",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 69,
            "name": "Prof. Reinhold Stanton Jr.",
            "profile_id": 18,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Prof. Stefan Kirlin Sr.",
            "location": "Krystaltown",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Nemo quos totam voluptates numquam sint.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?10383",
            "email": "talia02@example.com",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 70,
            "name": "Oda Wolff DVM",
            "profile_id": 19,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Rodrigo Legros",
            "location": "Port Jennings",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Qui omnis placeat totam sapiente.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?31712",
            "email": "ddare@example.org",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 71,
            "name": "Delpha Stark",
            "profile_id": 20,
            "profile_type": "music-expert",
            "surname": "Mr. Jorge Tromp",
            "location": "Hansenshire",
            "sex": "male",
            "bio": "Ea praesentium qui maiores nihil adipisci suscipit minus qui.",
            "featured_image": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?31960",
            "email": "thompson.keenan@example.org",
            "birthday": null,
            "value": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How many items are actually received as `props.profiles` in your `CustomComponent`? Have you tried [`initialNumToRender`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#initialnumtorender) prop of the `FlatList`? Try setting it to 20 and see what happens.

Comment: The issue is that I receive an indeterminate array... I have done the test of sending 12 elements and in the FlatList only iterate 6 elements...

Answer (score 0):

because you getting an array of object you should change to receive in that way `data={ this.props.profiles[0]},` in my case its work